# Computing the number of conjugacy-classes in $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ of elementary abelian p-subgroups by GAP and Magma

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems, magma

I'm trying to compute the number of conjugacy-classes of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank $2$ in $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ by GAP and Magma. So I consider the following GAP function:

```
myfunction:= function(n,p)
local G, S, cclS, cclG;
  G := Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(GL(n,p)));
  S := SylowSubgroup(G,p); 
  cclS := Filtered(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(S),
    cl->Size(Representative(cl))=p^2
    and not IsCyclic(Representative(cl)));
  cclG := List(EquivalenceClasses(cclS,
    function(cl1,cl2)
      return IsConjugate(G,Representative(cl1),
        Representative(cl2));
  end),Representative);
  cclG := List(cclG,cl->Representative(cl)^G);
  return Sum(List(cclG,Size));
end;
```

**Questions:**
Is there something I missed in this algorithm?

Is there a similar algorithm with  Magma which give the required computation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please indent GAP code by 4 spaces instead of using LaTeX notation - this way, the code will be rendered as code and it will be possible to copy and paste it into a GAP session.

Comment: Downvote for changing the question after you got an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will return the question to its original context. For clarification, see the comment in ahulpke's answer.

Answer (score 6):

This calculation should work, but you do a lot of extra work (calculating all subgroups of the Sylow subgroup) which you do not really need. This can become quite costly, in particular once the dimension $n$ becomes larger.
What will be more efficient is to find the subgroups from possible generating sets, e.g. by using:

```
cclG:=List(IsomorphicSubgroups(G,AbelianGroup([p,p])),Image);
```

(replacing the lines from `S:=...` down to `...Representative);`

Since your function only returns the count of the total number of subgroups in these classes, this can be done even faster: Count, for each element $g\in G$ of order $p$, the number of elements of order $p$ in $C_G(g)$ outside $\langle g\rangle$, and to divide the result by the order of $GL_2(p)$ (to make up for the different generating systems for the same subgroup):

```
cl:=Filtered(ConjugacyClasses(G),x->Order(Representative(x))=p);
return Sum(
  List(cl,x->Size(x)*Sum(List(Filtered(ConjugacyClasses(Centralizer(x)),
    y->Order(Representative(y))=p
    and not Representative(y) in Group(Representative(x))),Size))))/Size(GL(2,p));
```

Presumably one could implement the same algorithm in Magma, but why would one want to do this?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact the given GAP function  computes the number of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank 2 in $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$  and not just the conjugacy-classes.

Comment: Yes, the last command couts (as your function) all subgroups